# ADODB RecordSet.RecordCount property always returns -1

Tags: sql, excel, vba, t-sql, recordset

The below code exports data correctly however my `debug.print` line always gives  -1. I would like to retrieve the count of rows in `debug.print` statement. Please suggest what is wrong.

```
Sub TEST()

        Dim rs As Object
        Dim iCols As Integer
        Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        On Error GoTo ERR
        Dim SQLSTR As String, MYVAL As String
        MYVAL = InputBox("Enter Query")
        SQLSTR = " " & MYVAL & ""
        CONNECT_TO_DWHS
        rs.Open SQLSTR, PERSONALDBCONT

            For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                ActiveSheet.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
            Next
         Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

        CLOSE_CONNECTION_TO_SQL

            With ActiveWindow
                .SplitColumn = 0
                .SplitRow = 1
                .FreezePanes = True
            End With

        Exit Sub

   ERR:
        CLOSE_CONNECTION_TO_SQL
        MsgBox "There was an error"

  End Sub
```

Comment: I *think* it's because of the decrementation that takes place in the FOR operation. In order for the loop to stop, the last operation that is executed is a decrementation by 1 of the `rs.Fields.Count` value, which turns to `-1` in order for the loop to end. Because of this, *I think* the `print` will always show you -1. (*but this is just an idea and it's totally not a programmer's type of response, which should be precise*). To check this, I suggest you move the `print` inside the loop.. or maybe even print the record count before the loop..

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the cursor location. Specify the cursor location before opening the connection.

```
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open SQLSTR, PERSONALDBCONT
For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
  ActiveSheet.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
Next
Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
```

Please read this article: http://www.geeksengine.com/article/recordcount-ado-recordset-vba.html

Answer (score 0):

When you open a `RecordSet` as `ForwardOnly` (default if you don't explicit declare the cursor type) the RecordCount property returns -1.

For more check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).